# How to call a method even if app is not running? iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am building an app that requires core date to update every Sunday. e.g. it will save "thisWeek"'s data to "lastWeek" every beginning of a new week, and reset "thisWeek" to let user input new data for new week.

My question is how to achieve this even if user is not running the app at all?

Comment: Depends.  Jailbroken or Not?  APNS or Local notifications enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do the archiving if necessary whenever the user starts the app. If your data is timestamped this should be simple and there is no requirement for the phone to even be switched on.

Answer (score 2):

Use `UILocalNotification` with `repeatInterval` property which reschedule the notification with calendar interval. I suggest to go through following Apple iOS guidelines. Bottom line, your app will be open when notification will occur.

[UILocalNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/fireDate)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible. Your application cannot execute code unless the user has launched it. You could provide a local notification to prompt the user to reopen the app, however this is a sub-optimal solution.

A better solution would be to timestamp your data and then whenever the user opens the app, regardless of when, you can process all of the data and move it where it needs to go.